# Reject non-existent users in Postfix with Maildrop

Tags: postfix, email

I use Postfix with virtual mailbox and Maildrop for the transport agent. All my emails are delivered to the folder `/home/vmail/domain.tld/user/`. Today I noticed that emails sent to non-existent addresses are delivered to the file `/home/vmail/domain.tld/user`. I would rather have them rejected by the server with an error message to the sender.

I think it is responsible to the `/etc/postfix/maildroprc` file that contains the rules `DEFAULT="/home/vmail/$1/$2"`

The file `/etc/postfix/main.cfg`

```
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_transport = maildrop
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

The rule in `/etc/postfix/master.cfg`

```
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
   flags=ODRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop /etc/postfix/maildroprc ${domain} ${user} ${extension} ${recipient} ${user} ${nexthop}
```

Any idea how I can specify a list of valid emails ? All the emails addresses (except redirections which are in `virtual`) are listed in the `vmailbox` database but it seems not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.postfix.org/LOCAL_RECIPIENT_README.html

You have to correctly set `local_recipient_maps` in `main.cf`. This depends on how you manage users (system users, mysql, etc).

It could be something like `local_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql-recipients.cf` for mysql.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work well. In my case, it was `local_transport = virtual` and `local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps` (I use virtual mailbox, not mysql)